# How to Parse the multi value comma delimited file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sh, ksh

I have a comma delimited file which has 6 fields, whereas we have received comma as a value of the field and it is enclosed with "". I have to replace that comma with hiphen.

Input as

```
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded, closed",True,59
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,True,55
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded, awaiting reply",False,46
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,False,51
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,Responded,False,31
```

And expected output as

```
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded- closed",True,59
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,True,55
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded- awaiting reply",False,46
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,False,51
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,Responded,False,31
```

Comment: Use a language that has a proper CSV parser. Most shell tools work with regular expressions, which aren't sufficient for recognizing a valid CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Using `FPAT` in gnu-awk you can do this:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/,/, "-", $i)} 1' file.csv
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded- closed",True,59
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,True,55
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded- awaiting reply",False,46
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,False,51
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,Responded,False,31
```

Using `sed` you can do this:

```
sed -E ':a; s/("[^,"]+),([^"]*")/\1-\2/g; ta;' file.csv
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded- closed",True,59
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,True,55
03/03/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,"Responded- awaiting reply",False,46
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CALL,Responded,False,51
02/24/2016,Customer Service,CHAT,Responded,False,31
```

Comment: ++ for the nice AWK solution

Comment: As i m not using gnu-awk, the command returns the output come as below  $ awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/,/, "-", $i)} 1' file.csv
03/03/2016-Customer,Service-CHAT-"Responded-,closed"-True-59
02/24/2016-Customer,Service-CALL-Responded-True-55 
03/03/2016-Customer,Service-CHAT-"Responded-,awaiting,reply"-False-46  
02/24/2016-Customer,Service-CALL-Responded-False-51 
02/24/2016-Customer,Service-CHAT-Responded-False-31

Comment: `FPAT` is only supported in gnu-awk so it won't work on older awk versions.  Try my suggested `sed` command

Comment: gawk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/,/, "-", $i)} 1' file.csv 
giving the same output

and sed not at all working for me.

sed -E ':a; s/("[^,"]+),([^"]*")/\1-\2/g; ta;' file.csv
sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: [You can see here in this demo that awk command works perfectly](http://ideone.com/ZRwy5N)

Comment: The same command does not working for me. Can you pls help me out on this

Comment: I've already helped as much as I can. If a command woks on my system as well as on the Ideone demo then issue is your older awk version. I've also provided an alternate working sed command and that also you can try on ideone and it will work.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. Much appreciated. I am try to fix it out

Comment: This will not handle fields that contain double quotes. RFC 4180 allows a double-quote to be escaped by doubling it: `field1, "field ""2"" with 2 in quotes", "field 3"`.

Comment: By no means this is a fully featured CSV parser. This is targeted for the sample data provided in OP.

Comment: It is possible in ksh to parse csv, including quotes. I don't recommend it.

Comment: Yes full fledged CVS parser cannot be built using just shell utilities. Stronger languages like PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby etc better